# Only serve requests to a specific domain?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-10.04

I'd like to only server requests that are made to a specific domain and just drop everything else or give it 404. Would prefer to see it done through nginx but would of course like the best solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you setup Nginx, set your "server block" to be specific rather than general. This one would only pick up traffic going to www.domain1.com.

```
http {
  index index.html;

  server {
    server_name www.domain1.com;
    access_log logs/domain1.access.log main;

    root /var/www/domain1.com/htdocs;
  }
}
```

Where as this one would pick up all traffic to port 80.

```
http {
  index index.html;

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
    access_log logs/default.access.log main;

    server_name_in_redirect off;

    root  /var/www/default/htdocs;
  }    
}
```

More info:
http://wiki.nginx.org/ServerBlockExample

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot for the talk through. The default config I copied from had a listen 80; in there and when I removed it everything worked as expected. Thanks again for this!